# Is ROWID in SQLite automatically set?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

So, I have this application on Ionic that uses the [SQLite ngCordova plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) for internal storage. On it, I create a table with the following command:

```
db.executeSql(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Scans_table (" +
      //"id         TEXT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL," +
      "name       TEXT              NOT NULL," +
      "comment    TEXT, " +
      "text       TEXT              NOT NULL, " +
      "format     TEXT              NOT NULL, " +
      "dateTaken  TEXT              NOT NULL, " +
      "imgSource  TEXT              NOT NULL)", ... );
```

According to [this](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), if I don't have a column that is a primary key and an integer, a ROWID should be set as a unique identifier.

The problem is, when I query the table with a simple `SELECT * ...` I see all the rows that I set, and not the ROWID.

Is there a different way to set/check the ROWID?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), your table *does* have an internal `rowid` column. However, if your table's column list does not include an alias for this column (i.e., an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column), the `rowid` column is not included in `SELECT *`.

You can just add the column in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT rowid, * FROM Scans_table ...
```

However, if you actually use the `rowid`, it is a better idea to have an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column. This not only documents the table structure better, but also prevents the `rowid` values from being [changed by the VACUUM statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).

Answer (score 1):

in SqliteStudio 3.4.3, Place () around rowid: "select (rowid),* from asso" NOTE Python code with Sqlite3 does not need ().

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can get **ROWID** as shown below according to [the doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055819/sqlite-integer-primary-key-not-null-constraint-failed/77224788#77224788):

```sql
SELECT rowid FROM person;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT oid FROM person;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT _rowid_ FROM person;
```

And, you can also create a custom `rowid` column by omitting the default `rowid` column as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055819/sqlite-integer-primary-key-not-null-constraint-failed/77224788#77224788) explains how to insert a row with a custom `PRIMARY KEY` column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  name TEXT
) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

Then, you can get **ROWID** as shown below. *`oid` and `_rowid_` give you error in this case:

```sql
SELECT rowid FROM person;
```