# sqlite integer primary key not null constraint failed

Tags: database, sqlite, primary-key, notnull, rowid

According to the SQLite documentation / FAQ a column declared `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` will automatically get a value of +1 the highest of the column if omitted.
Using SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Creating a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  demo_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  ttt VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  basic VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE(ttt, basic) ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK
) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

Then inserting like this:

```
INSERT INTO test (ttt, basic, name) VALUES ('foo', 'bar', 'This is a test');
```

gives:

```
Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: test.demo_id
sqlite>
```

When it is expected to create a record with a demo_id value of 1. Even if the table already contains values, it'll fail inserting the row without explicitly specifying the id with the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems the same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49963559) (which comes with some good answers).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a Primary Key with a WithoutRowID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49963559/using-a-primary-key-with-a-withoutrowid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) says that you get autoincrementing values for the `rowid`. But you specified [WITHOUT ROWID](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html#differences_from_ordinary_rowid_tables).

Comment: To avoid confusions: "autoincrementing" in this answer is a broader term than SQLite's [AUTOINCREMENT](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) keyword. Both are only possible in ROWID tables, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a table with `WITHOUT ROWID` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

Then, you need to specify the value for the `PRIMARY KEY` column to insert a row because auto-increment doesn't work:

```sql
                    ↓↓                ↓
INSERT INTO person (id, name) VALUES (3, 'John');
```

Or:

```sql
                           ↓
INSERT INTO person VALUES (3, 'John');
```

In addition, you can manually create auto-increment as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO person (id, name) 
VALUES ((SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id), 0) + 1 FROM person), 'John');
```

Or:

```sql
INSERT INTO person 
VALUES ((SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id), 0) + 1 FROM person), 'John');
```