# C# System.Data.SQLite details on how a row was built

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I'm writing a lot of pretty complex `SQLite` queries, and what I'd like to do is gather information on how exactly a given row, returned from the query was constructed.

For example:

```
Execute complex SQL query
Returns 1 row
Read from `Table1` row 1
Read from `Table2` row 6
Read from `Table3` row 69
etc...
```

I've looked into the `SQLiteConnection.Trace` event, but it doesn't seem to contain the information I'm looking for.  I'm not sure if this is a terrible idea, and I should do it another way.

Any information or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: _”… but it doesn't seem to contain the information I'm looking for.”_ … what information are you looking for?

Comment: The information shown above, which tables and which rows the row was generated from.

Comment: Are you looking for [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html)?

Comment: Explain query plan provides some clear information on what is happening, but it doesn't provide information on exactly which rows, within which tables are being accessed.  Thanks though

Comment: Take a look at the answer for [Is ROWID in SQLite automatically set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050641/is-rowid-in-sqlite-automatically-set)

Comment: You can turn on [PRAGMA vdbe_trace=ON](https://www.sqlite.org/vdbe.html) on a build of SQLite without the NDEBUG macro set.  It's more detailed than literally what you're asking for, but afaik, it's the only way to get the data you want.

Comment: @AnonCoward that's interesting thanks!  Although I'm using the C# .NET System.Data.SQLite, and I'm not sure I can do this with that.  I'll check it out though